# Finding the largest connected component in an adj matrix graph?

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, matrix

I'm trying to find out it there is a way of finding the largest connected component in a adj matrix graph. Such as this:

```
0000000110
0001100000
0000000000
0100000010
0100000100
0000000100
0000000000
1000110000
1001000000
0000000000
```

I've Google'd the problem and am struggling to find anything, I've also read though the wiki article on graph theory and no joy. I assume their must be an algorithm out there to solve this problem. Can anybody point me in the right direction and give me some pointers on what I should be doing to solve this myself?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pick a starting point and start "walking" to other nodes until you have exhausted. Do this until you have found all components. This will run in `O(n)` where `n` is the size of the graph.

A skeleton of a solution in Python:

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, index, neighbors):
        self.index = index
        # A set of indices (integers, not Nodes)
        self.neighbors = set(neighbors)

    def add_neighbor(self, neighbor):
        self.neighbors.add(neighbor)


class Component(object):
    def __init__(self, nodes):
        self.nodes = nodes
        self.adjacent_nodes = set()
        for node in nodes:
            self.adjacent_nodes.add(node.index)
            self.adjacent_nodes.update(node.neighbors)

    @property
    def size(self):
        return len(self.nodes)

    @property
    def node_indices(self):
        return set(node.index for node in self.nodes)

    @property
    def is_saturated(self):
        return self.node_indices == self.adjacent_nodes

    def add_node(self, node):
        self.nodes.append(node)
        self.adjacent_nodes.update(node.neighbors)


adj_matrix = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
              [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
matrix_size = len(adj_matrix)

nodes = {}
for index in range(matrix_size):
    neighbors = [neighbor for neighbor, value in enumerate(adj_matrix[index])
                 if value == 1]
    nodes[index] = Node(index, neighbors)

components = []
index, node = nodes.popitem()
component = Component([node])
while nodes:
    if not component.is_saturated:
        missing_node_index = component.adjacent_nodes.difference(component.node_indices).pop()
        missing_node = nodes.pop(missing_node_index)
        component.add_node(missing_node)
    else:
        components.append(component)

        index, node = nodes.popitem()
        component = Component([node])

# Final component needs to be appended as well
components.append(component)

print max([component.size for component in components])
```

Comment: So something like a depth-first search could be used for this?

Comment: Yes. I'll try to outline a solution for you in Python, as this is a fun problem. The solution I had in mind is more breadth-first though.

Comment: DFS and BFS are equivalent for this particular purpose. I would go with BFS because it's ever so slightly easier to implement (queue instead of a stack), but any CS major worth their salt should be able to code both. Refer to the bible (CLRS *Introduction to Algorithms*) if you get stuck.

Comment: Thanks for python interpretation @bossylobster . It's been an excellent help.

Comment: This is O(n^2) because you have to iterate through n sized array for each node. Since you have to check every position on the adjacency matrix, even though some may be 1s, some may be 0s.

Answer (score 7):

1. Apply a connected components algorithm.

   For an undirected graph, just pick a node and do a breadth-first search. If there are any nodes left over after the first BFS, pick one of the left-overs and do another BFS. (You get one connected component per BFS.)

   Note that directed graphs require a slightly stronger algorithm to find the *strongly connected* components. Kosaraju's algorithm springs to mind.
2. Count the number of nodes in each of the connected components from (1). Pick the largest one.

Comment: This is an undirected graph im applying it to. Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<list>
using namespace std;
class GraphDfs
{
    private:
        int v;
        list<int> *adj;
        int *label;
        int DFS(int v,int size_connected)
        {

            size_connected++;
            cout<<(v+1)<<"   ";
            label[v]=1;
            list<int>::iterator i;
            for(i=adj[v].begin();i!=adj[v].end();++i)
            {
                if(label[*i]==0)
                {
                    size_connected=DFS(*i,size_connected);

                }

            }
            return size_connected;
        }
    public:
        GraphDfs(int k)
        {
            v=k;
            adj=new list<int>[v];
            label=new int[v];
            for(int i=0;i<v;i++)
            {
                label[i]=0;
            }
        }
        void DFS()
        {
            int flag=0;
            int size_connected=0;
            int max=0;
            for(int i=0;i<v;i++)
            {   
                size_connected=0;
                if(label[i]==0)
                {
                    size_connected=DFS(i,size_connected);
                    max=size_connected>max?size_connected:max;
                    cout<<size_connected<<endl;
                    flag++;
                }
            }
            cout<<endl<<"The number of connected compnenets are "<<flag<<endl;
            cout<<endl<<"The size of largest connected component is "<<max<<endl;
            //cout<<cycle;
        }

        void insert()
        {
            int u=0;int a=0;int flag=1;
            while(flag==1)
            {   cout<<"Enter the edges in (u,v) form"<<endl;

                cin>>u>>a;
                adj[a-1].push_back(u-1);
                adj[u-1].push_back(a-1);
                cout<<"Do you want to enter more??1/0 "<<endl;
                cin>>flag;

            }
        }       
};
int main()
{
    cout<<"Enter the number of vertices"<<endl;
    int v=0;
    cin>>v;
    GraphDfs g(v);
    g.insert();
    g.DFS();
    system("Pause");     
}
```

Comment: I have done it by lists though...Just apply similar logic for matrix